# Cannot see the Restangular response data set in my chrome developer tools... is it bc my JSON contains nested JSON?

Tags: angularjs, mlab

I'm currently trying to get a basic RESTful service up that pulls my JSON objects from MongoLab rather than the file-based implementation which I had working in my sandbox. Each of my JSON objects contain a child array (their predecessor IDs):

```
{title: 'xxyy1', course_id: '10004', semester_hours: 3, detail: 'coursename1', predecessors: ['10001']},
{title: 'xxyy2', course_id: '10005', semester_hours: 3, detail: 'coursename2', predecessors: ['10001','10003','10004']},
{title: 'xxyy3', course_id: '10006', semester_hours: 3, detail: 'coursename3', predecessors: ['10001','10003','10004']},
{title: 'xxyy4', course_id: '10007', semester_hours: 3, detail: 'coursename4', predecessors: ['10004','10006']}
```

This works perfectly fine when stringing this up into angularJS, by simply pulling the course.title, course.course_id, etc. into an ng-repeat. Even the predecessors easily is managed by constructing it as direct JSON.

```
<span class="predecessors">{{course.predecessors | json}}</span>
```

However, when trying to pull this same dataset from MongoLab using Restangular as my resource provider, I'm unable to see any data responded in the view... actually, I cannot see any data anywhere. Using Chrome's dev tools, all I see is the following:

![Restangular Response]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgqRm.jpg

Am I missing something here? My Mongo implementation is as follows:

```
  RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
    id: 'course_id'
  });


  RestangularProvider.setListTypeIsArray(false);

  RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation, what, url) {

    var newResponse;
    if (operation === "getList" && what === "availableCourses") {

        console.log(response);

        newResponse = response.data.title;
        newResponse.course_id = response.data.course_id;
        newResponse.semester_hours = response.data.semester_hours;
        newResponse.detail = response.data.detail;
        newResponse.predecessors = response.data.predecessors;
    } else {
        newResponse = response.data;
    }
    return newResponse;
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the creator of Restangular.

So, when you're doing a getList, Restangular expects to get an Array as the response. In your case, when you're getting a list and the path is availableCourses, you're returning a string (the title) which has properties. So you're creating a "special" string with properties, it's not really common, nor compatible with Restangular.

If you want to get the list of all available courses, you need to return an array as the new response. So, what's the exact response from the server when you do the getList? If you giv eme that, I'll be able to help you easier on how to create this response extarctor.

Also take a look to this MongoLab example :), maybe It'll help you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview

Bests!

Comment: Hey Martin, thank you so much for replying! Your responses on StackOverflow are so helpful and are making a huge contribution towards getting this framework moving and adopted.

The response I am receiving from the server is just the static 'response' object that I showed in the imgur link from my original post. Should I be able to inspect this object in another fashion, or drill further in and see data? Or, is it staying as a baseline 'object' because it cannot extract the data set's contents?

Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, first of all, I'm pleased to help with this :). I've been using for some time now and it's made my life easier, so maybe doing it easier on toerh people is awesome. 

From what I see in the image, your response is actually empty. So you're getting an emtpy response from the server.

Check out the network tab in the Developer Console and see there what URL was requested and exactly what was responded. That will guide you on what's going on. And anyway, for the getList, your response should be an array, which yours isn't

Comment: Hey Martin, you were completely correct on the response being empty. I was having an issue with the response from MongoLab... once the object was responded correctly, I didn't even need to build a custom extractor in order to reference the nested JSON in my angular scope. Your library is champ. Great job. :)